# Terminating / stopping a Thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using threads to handle two timers, one the first timer stops the second starts.
The timers are running in a thread which never stops.
I want to use a button to stop the threads without killing the window (sys.exit()). I have also tried multiprocessing but that freeze the window.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from threading import Thread
import sys

global th_complete
th_complete= False
timer_on = False
stop_Thread =False

def timer_mode():
    global timer_on
    timer_on = True
    return timer_on

def stop_timer():
    global stop_Thread
    stop_Thread = True
    print ("want to stop the thread")
    #sys.exit()
    return stop_Thread

def start_timers(duree, duree2):
    if (timer_on == True):
        th = Thread(target=lambda: attendre(duree, duree2))
        th.start()
        print(stop_Thread)
        if (stop_Thread == True):
            th.join()
        #print ("start 1")
    return None

def attendre(duree, duree2):
    global duree_complete
    print("start1")
    for i in range(duree):
        message.set(str(duree - i) + "s")
        time.sleep(1)
    message.set("- fini -")
    print("start2")
    for i in range(duree2):
        message.set(str(duree2 - i) + "s")
        time.sleep(1)
    th = Thread(target=lambda: attendre(duree, duree2))
    th.start()
    print (stop_Thread)
    if (stop_Thread == True):
        th.join()
    return None

fen = Tk();
fen.geometry("290x100+600+700");
fen.title("Freeze vs no freeze")
message = StringVar();
#message.set("Attendre 5s")
Label(fen, textvariable=message).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
Button(fen, text="start_Timers", command=lambda: start_timers(15,5)).grid(row=2, column=2, padx=1, pady=20)
Button(fen, text="Timer_mode", command=lambda: timer_mode()).grid(row=2, column=3, padx=1, pady=20)
Button(fen, text="stop Timer", command=lambda: stop_timer()).grid(row=2, column=4, padx=1, pady=20)
fen.mainloop()
```

I ll greatly appreciate your help.
many thanks

Comment: "attendre" should check "stop_Thread" much earlier (at least before creating and starting a new thread) and more often and should return as soon as possible if stopping is requested.

Comment: You do not have a "thread which never stops".  Your thread will count up to the first limit, then count up to the second limit, then start ANOTHER copy of itself and exit.  That's can't be what you want.  Note that your "joins" will never happen, because `stop_Thread` is not true when it starts the thread.

Comment: Are you sure that `join()` does what you think it does? (Hint: `th.join()` does not do anything at all to the thread, `th`.) https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects-1